# Simplifying equations in Maple

Tags: math, maple, exponential, natural-logarithm

I am using maple (version 12) for the first time.

I want to invert the equations using any maths tool. I tried it using MAPLE.

I have given two equations in this form:

```
a=x*b^r + y*(b^s)*(c^t)  +  z*c^u
```

Now I want to flip this equation (invert this equation)

I want two equations for `a` and `b` in terms of c

e.g

```
a= 0.98989c^2 + 78c + 87

b= 56c + 89
```

These are not my results. I just gave an example.

Any advice?

My two equations are:

Equation#1 is:

```
a= 1.093*(b^0.002939) - 0.1887*(b^0.7637)*(c^0.2306) - 0.04425 *(c^0.9143)
```

Equation#2 is:

```
a= 1.088*(b^0.003058) -0.1813*(b^0.7627)*(c^0.2501) -0.03958 *(c^0.9365)
```

From Equation#1, i can find `b` equation. I put the `b`equation in Equation#2 . In this way equation#2  has only `a` and `c` variables.  i can get `a` equation. and then by putting this equation can get `b` equation ( with only `c` variables)

But these equations are very complex and it takes a lot of time to evaluate in MAPLE. How to simplify it? I tried to use natural log, but it doesnot give any answer. It just repeat my equation in command window.

```
ln(1.093*b^0.2939e-2-.1887*b^.7637*c^.2306-0.4425e-1*c^.9143)
```

Please guide me.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587751/simplifying-equations-in-maple-version-12

Comment: Cross-posted, and the other post already has answers. We also expect you to have done your research and couldn't find an answer before posting on S.O., which this question suggests you haven't yet.